# Persisting Bitmap When Activity Ends

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

Android experts, I need some help.  I'm an Android noob.  I have an application where I need to draw a bitmap using canvas from outside the main UI thread.  I stumbled onto the SurfaceView class and mocked up a quick demo.  I created a seperate bitmap instance and draw into it.  When the OnDraw for the surfaceView occurs, I copy this bitmap into the SurfaceView.  It works great until the activity ends by, for example, going back to the home screen.  At that point, the SurfaceView thread seems to stop, and I seem to lose the bitmap image I was working on.  When you return to the app, it starts all over from scratch.

I would like to create the bitmap image using the canvas 2D drawing calls from a thread that is seperate from the main UI thread for performance reasons.  I need to get that bitmap into the main user interface once in awhile.  And I need the bitmap image to be retained and continue to be drawn into (to keep it current) when the activity is paused or stopped.

Since you must do all drawing in the main UI thread the SurfaceView seems like the only solution.  But it doesn't quite work like I hoped either.

I need a background task or thread that NEVER stops running and I need to create a bitmap image there, and I need to get that bitmap into the main user interface once in awhile (say 10 hz updates).

HELP!  How do I do this?

Comment: Does creating a separate `process` work for you?

Comment: Hi Dark Crow, thanks for the super fast reply.  Can you explain in more detail?  Do you mean using C++, NDK, and a seperate process??  Sorry I'm still a noob.

Comment: You can create separate `process` which is not much encouraged in `Android Manifest`.

Comment: But how would a seperate process access the canvas API?  Can you do that?  And how do you create this seperate process?

Comment: ok, looks like you need to know more about `Services`. Now if you don't know a tab about `Services` in Android, you need to go to Documentation and read it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of Services and I think I understand them but you are not allowed to call the Android UI library from there if I understand correctly.

Comment: If your service is running on UI thread, you can. If your service is running on a separate thread then you can either use `Content Provider` or you can use `Bound Service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an asynctask to draw the image onto your ui.

However, the canvas needs to be redrawn when the app is re-opened. If you want to save the bitmap that you created you will need to store it somewhere. I think this can be handled using caching:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Else look into managing the bitmap yourself:

```
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading about AyncTasks and the UI actually so very timely!  I will look into the caching as well.  Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Welcome to StackOverflow. You should accept the answer to get it off the "unanswered" list though.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that.  I think I'd like to wait and see if there are any other ideas though.  Then I'll close it.